# Почему компонент повторно монтируется после изменения состояния? И как исправить?

Tags: reactjs, компоненты

При использовании связки Context + useReducer + children, дочерний компонент GoodsFilter почему-то заново монтируется после диспатча состояния, можно убедится в этом через консоль изменяя значение фильтра товаров. Вопрос: почему компонент GoodsFilter заново монтируется каждый раз при изменении стейта, и можно ли убрать этот лишний монтаж? так как изза этого я не могу сохранить локальное состояние компонента GoodsFilter, потому что оно постоянно инициализируется первоначальным значением

[image: Edit example of unexpected component re-mounting]

**GoodsContextProvider**

```
import { useReducer, createContext, useCallback } from "react";

export const GoodsContext = createContext()

const fakeApiCall = (inStockFilter) => {

    const data = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Apples', inStock: false, quantity: 0 },
        { id: 2, name: 'Oranges', inStock: true, quantity: 25 },
        { id: 3, name: 'Pears', inStock: true, quantity: 90 },
        { id: 4, name: 'Pineapples', inStock: false, quantity: 0 },
        { id: 5, name: 'Bananas', inStock: true, quantity: 43 },
        { id: 6, name: 'Mangoes', inStock: true, quantity: 15 },
    ]

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (inStockFilter === null) {
                return resolve(data)
            }
            resolve(data.filter(item => item.inStock === inStockFilter))
        }, 500);
    })
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'pending':
            return { ...state, loading: true }
        case 'success':
            return { ...state, loading: false, items: action.payload }
        case 'error':
            return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload }
        case 'setFilter':
            return { ...state, inStockFilter: action.payload }
        default:
            break;
    }
}

const initState = {
    items: [],
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    inStockFilter: null,
}

const GoodsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initState)

    const fetchGoods = useCallback(async () => {

        try {
            dispatch({ type: 'pending' })
            const data = await fakeApiCall(state.inStockFilter)
            dispatch({ type: 'success', payload: data })
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ type: 'error', payload: error })
        }
    }, [state.inStockFilter])

    return (
        <GoodsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch, fetchGoods }}>
            {children}
        </GoodsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default GoodsContextProvider
```

**App**

```
import GoodsScreen from "./components/GoodsScreen";
import GoodsContextProvider from "./context/GoodsContextProvider";

function App() {
  return (
    <GoodsContextProvider>
      <GoodsScreen />
    </GoodsContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**GoodsScreen**

```
import GoodsList from "./GoodsList"

const GoodsScreen = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <GoodsList />
        </div>

    )
}

export default GoodsScreen
```

**GoodsList**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { GoodsContext } from "../context/GoodsContextProvider"
import GoodsFilter from "./GoodsFilter"

const GoodsList = () => {

    const { state, fetchGoods } = useContext(GoodsContext)

    useEffect(() => {

        fetchGoods()

    }, [fetchGoods])


    if (state.loading) return <h3>loading...</h3>

    return (
        <>
            <GoodsFilter />
            <hr />
            <ul>
                {state.items.map((good => <li key={good.id}>{good.name} - {good.quantity}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export default GoodsList
```

**GoodsFilter**

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react"
import { GoodsContext } from "../context/GoodsContextProvider"

const GoodsFilter = () => {
  const [localState, setLocalState] = useState('init')

  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(GoodsContext)

  useEffect(() => {

    // you can notice, console.log executing on every time i changed a state
    console.log('Component mounted');

  }, [])

  const filterChangeHandler = (e) => {

    let filterValue = null

    if (e.target.value === 'true') filterValue = true
    if (e.target.value === 'false') filterValue = false

    // state changing is here
    dispatch({ type: 'setFilter', payload: filterValue })

    // also i can't save local state because of component mounting on every render
    setLocalState('my new test state')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select
        name="inStockFilter"
        onChange={filterChangeHandler}
        defaultValue={state.inStockFilter}
      >
        <option value='all'>show all</option>
        <option value='true'>in stock</option>
        <option value='false'>not available</option>
      </select>
      <p>local state is : {localState}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default GoodsFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел проблему.
Проблема была в компоненте GoodsList.jsx в котором крутился спиннер во время загрузки и изза этого компонент Filter.jsx дизмаунтился

```
if (state.loading) return <h3>loading...</h3>
```

**fixed version of GoodsList.jsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { GoodsContext } from "../context/GoodsContextProvider"
import GoodsFilter from "./GoodsFilter"

const GoodsList = () => {

    const { state, fetchGoods } = useContext(GoodsContext)

    useEffect(() => {

        fetchGoods()

    }, [fetchGoods])


    return (
        <>
            <GoodsFilter />
            {state.loading ? <h3>loading...</h3>
                :
                <>
                    <hr />
                    <ul>
                        {state.items.map((good => <li key={good.id}>{good.name} - {good.quantity}</li>))}
                    </ul>
                </>
            }

        </>
    )
}

export default GoodsList
```